# Getting 400 HTTP error when creating a new cloud composer environment in GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, airflow, google-cloud-composer

When creating a composer environment in GCP, I get this error:

```
Http error status code: 400 Http error message: BAD REQUEST Additional errors: {"ResourceType":"gcp-types/storage-v1:storage.buckets.insert","ResourceErrorCode":"400","ResourceErrorMessage":{"code":400,"errors":[{"domain":"global","message":"Invalid argument","reason":"invalid"}],"message":"Invalid argument","statusMessage":"Bad Request","requestPath":"https://www.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b","httpMethod":"POST"}}
```

It appears the GKE cluster is successfully created, and there is a failed k8s job named `composer-agent-a62cd8ef-f7a8-4797-c732-fc15673528e8`

Looking in the logs of the job's containers, I can see that a `gsutil cp` failed to some bucket named `us-central1-test-airflow--a62cd8ef-bucket`.

Looking in GCS, this bucket indeed doesn't exist.

I looked in stackdriver and found that the creation of this bucket indeed fails. Here is a sample stackdriver record of the failure:

```
{
insertId: "59zovdfe3w3r" 
 logName: "projects/analytics-analysis-1/logs/cloudaudit.googleapis.com%2Factivity" 
 protoPayload: {
  @type: "type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.audit.AuditLog"  
  authenticationInfo: {
   principalEmail: "234453461464@cloudservices.gserviceaccount.com"   
   serviceAccountDelegationInfo: [
    0: {
     firstPartyPrincipal: {
      principalEmail: "cloud-dm@prod.google.com"      
     }
    }
   ]
  }
  authorizationInfo: [
   0: {
    granted: true    
    permission: "storage.buckets.create"    
    resource: "projects/_/buckets/us-central1-test-airflow--a62cd8ef-bucket"    
    resourceAttributes: {
    }
   }
  ]
  methodName: "storage.buckets.create"  
  requestMetadata: {
   callerIp: "64.233.172.244"   
   callerSuppliedUserAgent: "Google-Deployment-Manager,gzip(gfe)"   
   destinationAttributes: {
   }
   requestAttributes: {
   }
  }
  resourceLocation: {
   currentLocations: [
    0: "us"    
   ]
  }
  resourceName: "projects/_/buckets/us-central1-test-airflow--a62cd8ef-bucket"  
  serviceName: "storage.googleapis.com"  
  status: {
   code: 3   
   message: "INVALID_ARGUMENT"   
  }
}
receiveTimestamp: "2019-04-05T09:29:59.198703635Z" 
 resource: {
  labels: {
   bucket_name: "us-central1-test-airflow--a62cd8ef-bucket"   
   location: "us"   
   project_id: "exp-project-airflow"   
  }
  type: "gcs_bucket"  
 }
severity: "ERROR" 
 timestamp: "2019-04-05T09:28:54.019Z" 
}
```

I am guessing the failure to create the bucket is what failing the entire airflow environment creation.

How do I solve this?

Comment: The GCS bucket is indeed required for the environment creation to complete. Do you have any domain policies or IAM-related restrictions in place, such as VPC-SC?

Comment: Yes, this looks like a error caused by VPCSC. Please whitelist the Cloud Deployment Manager service robot account ({project-number}@cloudservices.gserviceaccount.com) for VPCSC access through user identity: https://cloud.google.com/access-context-manager/docs/create-access-level#members-example.